# Is Python's bool sorting defined?

Tags: python, sorting

Is the ordering of True and False well defined in Python, or is it left as an implementation detail?

From the console, I'm seeing False sort before True...but I don't know if that's a behavior I should rely on or not.

(I'm sure there's some Python doc about this, but I can't find it...)

Comment: For bonus points, try doing arithmetic with bools. `(True + True) ** -True == 0.5`...

Comment: @JameySharp are you a wizard?

Comment: @rsegal I discovered that `sum([True, False, ...])` is a nice way to count the number of true cases in a list, and the above awful abuse followed quickly after.

Comment: @JameySharp that's actually not a terrible idea. It's almost like a `reduce(filter(list))`. Hmmmm.

Comment: and don't forget:
    `assert isinstance(True,int)`

Comment: @JameySharp `sum(1 for element in iterable if element)` should be well-defined.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

> **Booleans**: These represent the truth values False and True. The two objects representing the values False and True are the only Boolean objects. The Boolean type is a subtype of plain integers, and Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

This reads to me that the python language requires `False < True`, `False == 0`, `True == 1`, `True != 2`.

The same wording is retained in [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) as well.

Comment: If you're unsure you agree with sharth's understanding, try plugging it into an interpreter. You'll quickly verify that `False < True`. In fact, reading the spec and playing around with it into the interpreter are always good ideas!

Comment: It's worth noting that 'sorting is defined' basically means comparisons are defined, which means that if something is less than something else, it will be sorted correctly and as noted here `False < True`.

Answer (score 1):

We can show bool is sortable using the Python REPL, with `False` being the lower value:

```
>>> sorted([False, True, True, False, True])
[False, False, True, True, True]
```